# Flash AS3 Global Variables?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

HI i have a main class

```
//main.as

package {
    public class main {
        public var testGlobal:string = "testValue";

    }
}


//pop.as

package {
    public class pop {
        function pop():void {
            trace("testGloabl from main.as" + testGlobal);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get the testGlobal value on pop.as width out using a main class Object.
Is there any method of Global variables??

How to use global variables in AS3 .

Comment: Hey, did none of our answers satisfy you? Amarghosh's answer and my own cover pretty much everything you can possibly need. One of them at least should be considered an answer.

Comment: Yes, you should accept @alecmce's answer - it is the technically correct answer to "is there any method of Global variables?"

Answer (score 14):

If you absolutely positively have to have a global variable in as3, you could always create a file in the top-level of your source folder like this:

MULTIPLIER.as

```
package
{
    public var MULTIPLIER:int = 3;
}
```

Then, whenever you need your multiplier you could reference wherever you need it like this:

DoSomeMultiplying.as

```
package multiplying
{
    public class DoSomeMultiplying
    {
        public function multiplyMe(n:int):int
        {
            var m:int = n * MULTIPLIER;
            MULTIPLIER = m;
            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would ***strongly recommend that you do not do this!*** it is horribly bad practice, horribly slow and, well, just **horrible**!

But there it is, it is possible to create a global variable or constant in the default package to act as a global constant or variable.

**Declaring Global Functions in AS3**

Note that you can also create global functions in the same way, and you don't need to use an import statement for (similar to the built-in trace function):

greet.as

```
package {
  public function greet():String { return "Hello World" }
}
```

Similar to the global variable, this global function is accessible from anywhere without an import statement:

```
package bar {
    public class foo
    {
        public function foo():void
        {
            trace("New foo says: "+greet()+", no import necessary");
            // New foo says: Hello World, no import necessary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with alecmce THIS IS A HORRIBLE PRACTICE!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the reason this is A HORRIBLE PRACTICE is because another variable somewhere else might have the same name. Then you wouldn't be able to access the global variable from there (the scope where the other variable is), because it would override the global one.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I wanted a global debug function that I could use quickly and not have to add an import statement (basically like `trace`), and this is indeed the solution (although in my case, it's `public function()` as opposed to `public var`)  Of course you don't want to build code this way, but it's nice to know for certain circumstances.  To ensure these functions aren't included in a production build, you could put them in a separate `-source-path` and update your build scripts accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

testGlobal is not a global variable, it is a public instance variable of the `Main` class. You cannot access it without using a `Main` class object, because without an object there is no existence for a property. Instance variables are tied to objects.

If you want to access create a property that is not tied to any particular object instance, declare it as `static`.

```
//Main.as
package {
    public class Main {
        public static var testGlobal:string = "testValue";
    }
}


//Pop.as
package {
    public class Pop {
        function pop():void {
                trace("testGloabl from Main.as" + Main.testGlobal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok That i know, but i want a gloabl variable to set value from one class and get or access from diffrent class.. how is it possible??

Comment: You can get/set the public static variable `Main.testGlobal` from any class.

Comment: then how can i set a global variable in as3

Comment: If by `set` you mean to modify the value, this is how you do it `Main.testGlobal = "some other value"` - If you are looking for global variables in general, again, making a variable `public static` is the way to go.

Comment: how can i create a Global variable in AS3, is AS3 support Global variables like in AS2 ??

Comment: I am not familiar with AS2, but in AS3 `public static` variables are the closest you can get to global vars.

Comment: Not quite Amarghosh, my solution is closest to a global variable, albeit a weird one :)

Answer (score 3):

Just do this from any level you want to call the main timeline from:

```
//Define your global variable
var myGlobalVariable:String = "Get Up!";
//call it from anywhere
var Root:MovieClip = root as MovieClip;
trace(Root.myGlobalVar);
```

That should work anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static, like it was said before, or you can use the Singleton pattern. There are no private constructors in AS, so what you can do is:
a) be very carefull not to call the constructor
b) send an exception everytime someone calls the constructor and the instance has already been set.

I don't think there are actual global variables - but I don't see why you would need any. If you want a variable in class to be modifiable from the outside just declare it static then do className.variableName = .

Comment: @webdreamer, yes there are, if you must have them. I refer you to my post, which you appear to have ignored!

Comment: Well I said I don't think there are... That's because I'm not sure... All I wanted to do is to refer to the Singleton pattern as a pattern that is sometimes used to circumvent the problems of using global variables... I don't remember the specific day this was (10 days ago!) though I do remember your answer. I probably only noticed it after I posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what the others just said, avoid global variables, prefer constant (and usually constants are not meant to be changed)

Answer (score 0):

```
//main.as

package {
    public class main {
        public var testGlobal:string = "testValue";

    }
}


//pop.as

package {

public class pop {
    function pop():void {
        trace("testGlobal from main.as -- " + new main().testGlobal);
        // or
        var m : main = new main();
        trace(m.testGlobal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this from any level you want to call the main timeline from:

```
//Define your global variable
var myGlobalVariable:String = "Get Up!";
//call it from anywhere var Root:MovieClip = root as MovieClip;
trace(Root.myGlobalVar);
```

That should work anytime.

```
var i:int = 10000000;
while(i--){
    Root.nn--;
}
```

23 times slower than:

```
var i:int = 10000000;
while(i--){
    globalVar.nn--;  // package
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the _global keyword...

ex : a file named "_global.as" with this code:

```
public var _global:* = activateGlobals();

public function activateGlobals():*{
    if(_global == null){
        _global = this;
    }
    return _global;
}
```

Then you can test _global as hereunder in a class eg "Main2.as" (have fun):

```
package classes {
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class Main2 extends flash.display.Sprite{
    include "_global.as";
    var globalMethod:Function;
    var globalID;
    var globalValue:Number;
    var innerMethod:Function;
    var factorial:Function;
    var prototype = Main2.prototype;
    Main2.prototype.globalID = "globalIDprototype";
    Main2.prototype.globalValue = Math.PI*2;
    public function Main2() {
        _global.factorial = function(n:Number) { 
            if (n<=1) { 
                return 1; 
            } else { 
                return n*_global.factorial(n-1); 
            } 
        } 
        prototype.setPropertyIsEnumerable("globalID",true);
        _global.globalMethod = function(){
            trace("Use of the _global method \"globalMethod()\"");
        }
        _global.globalID = "_global id";
        _global.globalValue = Math.PI;
        _global.globalMethod();
        // access properties :
        trace(_global.globalID);
        trace(_global.globalValue);
        trace(prototype.globalID);
        trace(prototype.globalValue);
        listValues();
        getNameInInnerMethod();
        _global.globalMethod();
        getNameInInnerMethod();
    }

    private function listValues():void{
        for(var i in prototype){
            trace(" - prototype[" + i + "] = " + prototype[i]);
        }
        for(i in _global){
            trace(" - _global[" + i + "] = " + _global[i]);
        }
        i = null; // optionnal
    }
    private function getNameInInnerMethod():void{
        _global.globalMethod = function(){
            trace("this.name = " + this.name);
            trace("_global.name = " + _global.name);
        }
        function innerMethod():void{
            trace("this.name = " + this.name);
            trace("_global.name = " + _global.name);
            // with global you have access to the name property from the inner method.
        }
        innerMethod();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can place `var testGlobal:string = "testValue";` in Frame 1