# how to define global variable in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

var frName = fruit_txt.text;

disp_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disp_fruit);

function disp_fruit(Event:MouseEvent)

{

dispName_txt.text = frName;

}

here I am displaying a name of fruit....
but defining the variable i:e frName.... outside the function it does not display anything..
same time if I define same variable inside function i:e disp_fruit...it displays the name

why?

and how can i use variable i:e frName as global var so that it can be used in any function???

Comment: I would advice you to refrain the question... the title has little to do with the explanation.

Comment: The problem you are stating is probably because your fruit_txt textfield is not yet initialized before you try to retrieve its text value. You probably need a method to set the frName variable once you know you can retrieve it's value.

Comment: As for global variables, there are quite a few threads already with good questions and answers... for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852070/flash-as3-global-variables

Answer (score 0):

Verify that fruit_txt is initialized when you assign fruit_txt.text to frName. Is that also global? Also, specify the type of frName.

Comment: what is initialization!!! I assigned a value of fruit_txt instance of input text to frName:string but I want frName:string as a Global variable

Comment: What is the value of fruit_txt when you assigned it to frName? If frName is global, the assignment statement will be executed before any of your functions. So unless fruit_txt is also a global variable and has already been initialized, frName will be null.

Comment: hmm.. when we render the program we will put the value inside fruit_txt which IS A INSTANCE OF INPUT TEXT and when I PRESS THE disp_btn WHICH IS A BUTTON I SHOULD GET value from fruit_txt and display it in dispName_txt.text as IT IS A INSTANCE OF DYNAMIC TEXT

Comment: Stop shouting. If you do not like the answer, you are free to downvote it. The arrows at the left of the answer are provided for just this purpose. I stand by my answer. Cay has also mentioned the same point about initialization. Check it out. Including a link to the FAQ for you to read. It has a fairly complete guide to good manners on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell from this code whether you have this in a package or not. If you had this code inside a Flash file on a timeline, from what I see this should work.

If you have this inside a package (and `.as` file) you would define it like this
`public var frName:String` or `private var frName:String`

but the class would have to be defined properly, if this doesn't make much sense look through this : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html

Comment: well I grabbed your code tested it and it worked, and from what you have shown it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: I grabbed your code, without any changes, put it on the first frame. Added two textboxes and a button and named them `fruit_txt`, `dispName_txt` and `disp_btn`. I typed something in the `fruit_txt` and it showed up.