# How to trace order of code execution in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm writing a mobile application in AIR and I often run into the same problem: what is the order of execution? I know that one can determine the order of initialization, creation, etc. for a UI class. I can also put trace statements into the constructor of every class, and do it that way.  But that's tedious.

Is there a generic piece of code that will have each class 'announce' itself as it loads? Has anyone written anything like this?

Pseudocode would be something like:

```
for each var class:Class in application
{
     trace(class.getQualifiedClassName.toString();
}
```

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's an example. I run MyApp.mxml and I put trace statements on it. The first view is a list which is populated by an array, which comes from a server via xml. But when the app loads, the list is blank. Why? Because of the following order of events, based on trace statements I've inserted manually:

```
MyApp::viewnavigatorapplication1_intitializeHandler firing
Model::initialize function firing
XMLLoader::going to http://mysite.com/myxml.xml
MyApp::addedToStageHandler running
HomeListView::viewActivateHandler firing
XMLLoader::xmlLoaded
```

The reason that the list is blank is that the xml is loaded *after* HomeListView has been activated. So it would be helpful to have a way to get all this info without having to write it in class after class. And note that not all classes are on the displaylist (e.g. Model and XMLLoader).

Comment: The order of execution of what?  Are you using Flex?  If so, the Flex Component LifeCycle controls order of execution of the lifecycle methods and you'll probably want to spend some time reading up about that.  I think most classes--whether Flex or not--will dispatch an "addedToStage" event.  However, I'm not clear if that fufills your definition of "load" in this case.

Comment: Yes, using Flex, and yes, I understand about the LifeCycle -- that's what I meant about 'determine the order of initialization' etc. Say I have 100 classes. What I'm asking is if there's a way to write a line or a few lines of code and have every class trace 'My constructor is running!' rather than having to go through and create a trace statement 100 times. This would be true for classes not on the displaylist as well for those that are.

Comment: You can create a Global Variable in AS3 like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1860855/133840 but I don't think that will do what you need.  You almost need a Global constructor trace statement.  You may have to go as far up in the class hierarchy as you can and tweak that constructor to add your code.  It may involve recompiling the Flex Framework.  And you'll have to do the same thing for every class hierarchy you have; as you won't be able to edit the master Flash "Object" class.  I'm not sure what purpose this would serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `AS3Trace` in an mm.cfg file will give the complete firehose of executing functions.

See [this blog post](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/) for other hidden mm.cfg features, and [here is some help](http://blogs.adobe.com/rajorshi/2012/03/23/obtaining-trace-output-logs-on-device-for-air-on-ios/) getting mm.cfg running in your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something close to what you want:

```
var numChildren:Number = this.numChildren;
for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    var displayObject:DisplayObject = this.getChildAt(i);
    displayObject.addEventListener(FlexEvent.INITIALIZE, function (e:FlexEvent):void {
        trace("child " + displayObject.name +" is initializing" );
    });
    displayObject.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function (e:FlexEvent):void {
        trace("child " + displayObject.name +"'s creation is completed" );
    });                     
}
```

You need to add it to your main application's `initialize` event handler.

Comment: Yes, very good. Is there a way to do this for classes not on the displaylist? I've added an edit with additional clarification above.

Comment: I don't think this will give @David everything he wants, as this isn't recursive, so children of children are not covered here.  Second, the initialize event of a child component will dispatch before the initialize event of the parent; so the initialize event listener is added after the initialize event fires.