# assigning a value into a global variable action script 3 inside a function

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

i'm new to as3.
I declared a global variable that receives the length of my images in xml. I created a function for xml load completion,once the xml data are completely loaded I get the length.
I've traced it inside the function and outputs the correct number of my specified node but when I trace it outside, the value is gone...how can I make the value be assigned globally, not only in the function...ty

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared inside a function is visible to the contents of that function only.  If you want to get to it outside that function, declare a variable at least at the same scope you declare the function, something like :

```
var myXmlLength:Number;

function onXmlComplete( evt:Event ):void
{
    myXmlLength = evt.target.data.length;
}

trace( myXmlLength );
```

Also, make sure you are tracing the whole path to where you declared the variable.  For instance, if you have the variable declared 3 movieclips deep your trace might look like:

```
trace( mc1.mc2.mc3.myXmlLength );
```

Please note this is pseudo code, and won't actually do anything, as I do not know quite how you have your code set up.

If you want a truly global variable, available to everything, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852070/flash-as3-global-variables), or look up singletons in as3, (a debated but nontheless useful approach).