# Reading Multidimentional Array in AS3 from loaded SWF

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I got a multidimensional array in my Main.as:

```
public static var intro:Object = new Object(); 
intro["item1"] = ["3"];
intro["item2"] = ["1"];
```

And I am trying to call it's content from a loaded SWF:

```
var theParent:Object;
theParent = this.parent.parent.parent as Object;
trace(theParent.intro.item1[0]);
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property intro not found on Main and there is no default value.
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Is the `Loader` directly added to stage or is child of a movieclip?

Comment: Try make the _intro_ object non static..

Comment: I think that what you need is in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852070/flash-as3-global-variables

Comment: It's solved. I created a public function that returns the data instead of trying to bring it directly to the swf. I'll post the complete solution later. Thanks!