# Can I still create Global variables in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, global

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1860855/310967), I have created a file called MyGlobals.as and placed some global variables and functions so that I can access it from anywhere within my project just like AS3 buil-in functions such as `trace()` method.

This is MyGlobals.as which is located in the `src` folder (top level folder)

```
package {

    public var MessageQueue:Array = new Array();
    public var main:Main;
    public var BOOKING_STATUS_DATA:Object;


    public function postMessage(msg:Object):void {

        MessageQueue.push(msg);

    }
    public function processMessage():void {

        var msg:Object = MessageQueue.pop();

        if (msg) {

            switch (msg.type) {



            }


        }

}
```

Looks like my IDE (FD4) is also recognizing all these functions and variables and also highlighting the varibles and functions just like any other built-in global functions. However, I am getting compilation  errors "Accessing possibly undefined variable xxx". The code is as simple as `trace(MessageQueue)` inside my Main (or another classe).

I am wondering if there was any change Adboe has done recently that it can't be done now or am I missing something? I am not sure if I need to give any special instructions to FD to include this MyGlobals.as?

I am using FD4, Flex SKD 3.1, FP12.0

I am aware of the best practices which suggests to avoid using this type of method for creating global variables but I really need it for my project for my comfort which I feel best way (right now) when compared to take any other path which involves daunting task of code refactoring. I just want do something which can be done in AS3 which I guess is not a hack.

Comment: Any reason not to use a class with static class members?

Comment: 1 - Comfort & Feasibility. 2 - the solution provided in the linked post is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some playing around; it looks like *you can only define **one (1)** property or method at package level per .as file*. It must be the same name (case-sensitive) as the .as file it is contained in.

So no, *nothing has changed since the older Flash Versions*.

In your case that would mean you need five separate ActionScript files along the lines of:

`MessageQueue.as`:

```
package
{
    public var MessageQueue:Array;
}
```

`main.as`:

```
package
{
    public var main:Main;
}
```

...etc. As you can see this is very cumbersome, another downside to the many others when using this approach. I suggest using the singleton pattern in this scenario instead.

Comment: I am aware of this, like I mentioned in my post I am not looking for other alternative methods.

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper Suit yourself. I suggest [reading this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852070/flash-as3-global-variables), it might help.

Comment: In fact that is the post which I got idea to define global variables. Updated the post. Its not working and thats what is my question whether if there is anything has since last few years.

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper OK, I've done some experimenting for you; have a read of my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
package{
public class Singleton{
    private static var _instance:Singleton=null;
    private var _score:Number=0;
    public function Singleton(e:SingletonEnforcer){
        trace(‘new instance of singleton created’);
    }
    public static function getInstance():Singleton{
        if(_instance==null){
            _instance=new Singleton(new SingletonEnforcer());
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    public function get score():Number{
        return _score;
    }
    public function set score(newScore:Number):void{
        _score=newScore;
    }
}
```

}

then iin your any as3 class if you import the singleton class

import Singleton

thn where u need to update the global var_score

use for example

```
var s:Singleton=Singleton.getInstance();
s.score=50;
trace(s.score);
```

same thing to display the 50 from another class

```
   var wawa:Singleton=Singleton.getInstance();
```

trace(wawa.score)