# Making variables global in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I make this variable global - can be called from everywhere/anywhere in the source paths?

```
public var newLine:String = "\n";
```

or

```
public function get newLine():String {
    return "\n";
}
```

P.S: I'm reading the Clean Code book. In Chapter 11: Systems: Separate Constructing a System from Using It: Separation of Main, it says `Notice the direction of the dependency arrows crossing the barrier between 'main' and the application. They all go one direction, pointing away from 'main'. This means that the application has no knowledge of main or of the construction process.` If I understand it right, I shouldn't put the variable in the Main class, should I?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash AS3 Global Variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852070/flash-as3-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating global variables:

1. Use static variable. Add `static` before `var`:

   ```
   public static var newLine:String = "\n";
   ```

   So you can address to this variable by typing:

   ```
   YourClass.newLine
   ```
2. Use Singletone pattern.

   ```
   package
   {
       public class Singleton
       {
           private static var instance:Singleton;

           public var newLine:String = "\n";

           public function Singleton()
           {
               if (instance)
                   throw new Error("Use getInstance()");
               instance = this;
           }

           public static function getInstance():Singleton
           {
               if (!instance)
                   new Singleton();
               return instance;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   So you can address to the `newLine` variable by typing:

   ```
   Singleton.getInstance().newLine
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
package { 
    public function get newline():String {
        return "\n";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myText:String = "Hello" + newline;
```